# Multiple Parent Child trees in one table. Select down each tree from a node value

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table containing three trees:

```
   T1      T2      T3     T4
   --      --      --     --

   A       F       B      H
  |  |    |  |    |  |    |
  B  C    B  C    A  C    I
 | |      |               |
 D E      D               B
 |                        |
 G                        J
```

I'd like to be able to get the `distinct` nodes sitting under a specific node value.

So for `B` that'd be `D, E, G`, `D`, `A, C` and `J` where the `distinct` is `A, C, D, E, G, J`

```
declare @t table (t_id int, parent_t_id int, tree varchar(2), item varchar)

insert into @t

select 1, 0, 'T1', 'A' union 
select 2, 1, 'T1', 'B' union 
select 3, 1, 'T1', 'C' union 
select 4, 2, 'T1', 'D' union 
select 5, 2, 'T1', 'E' union 
select 5, 4, 'T1', 'G' union 

select 6, 0, 'T2', 'F' union 
select 7, 6, 'T2', 'B' union 
select 8, 6, 'T2', 'C' union 
select 9, 7, 'T2', 'D' union 

select 10, 0,  'T3', 'B' union 
select 11, 10, 'T3', 'A' union 
select 12, 10, 'T3', 'C' union

select 13, 0,  'T4', 'H' union 
select 14, 13, 'T4', 'I' union 
select 15, 14, 'T4', 'B' union
select 16, 15, 'T4', 'J' 

select * from @t
```

I suspect a CTE is required?

Comment: Have a look at [Hierarchies on Steroids](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Hierarchy/94040/). You could do it with a CTE, however, depending how large your tree is, the performance can/will get exponentially worse.

Comment: I don't mind about performance as this is a one off. 19,000 rows. 9,000 trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
;with cte as
    (

        Select t1.* From @t t1
        JOIN @t t2 on t1.parent_t_id=t2.t_id AND t1.tree=t2.tree
        Where t2.item =@Item

        Union All

        Select t1.* From @t t1
        JOIN cte t2 on t1.parent_t_id=t2.t_id AND t1.tree=t2.tree       
    )

    Select  DISTINCT Item FROM cte
```

Comment: I've added an additional branch in the first tree as example was too simplistic

Comment: I enhanced the example further and this works. Good work!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CTE can be an option

```
SELECT * FROM @t ORDER BY t_id 
;WITH myCTE (Id, ParentId,Item)
AS
(SELECT  t_Id ,Parent_t_Id ,Item
 FROM  @t
 UNION ALL
 SELECT  t_Id ,Parent_t_Id ,t1.Item
 FROM @t t1
 INNER JOIN myCTE tmp ON tmp.ParentId    = t1.t_Id
 )

 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM myCTE ORDER BY parentId
```